# Android : Is there any free PDF library for Android

Tags: android, pdf, mupdf

I need  a PDF library for manipulating  a  PDF documents, (creating PDF, image convertinng to PDF) and  things like that but in Android.

I tried the android itext port but the library project generates compile errors after I added it to my Project. Looks like it is still using some affinetransformation classes that are defined in AWT.

Comment: Ok , MvanGeest I  am  a  completely new here :) I  try  it with iText & on forums some people say it should work and some it does't ,  I was imported him in my project and fallow tutorial how to use it and nothing  happened .. try it few  time result nothing .there is no error  but in a place where I  want  to create a PDF there is nothing .

Comment: I used iText too. You can see my code at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530780/android-is-there-any-free-pdf-library-for-android.

Comment: Sridhar, check your link. It navigates to this page.

Comment: See https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer and https://android-arsenal.com/tag/72?sort=created&category=1.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems that no one of the pure java pdf libraries will work with android because they use libraries that aren't supported by android. I think I read that iText is interested in doing a port to android but thinks that google should support them if they did, haven't got a source on that though.

Here is a project in work for writing pdfs in android: [sourceforge.net/projects/apwlibrary](http://sourceforge.net/projects/apwlibrary/)
Haven't tried it and it says that it only does simple pdfs

Comment: softran I was on this link  before and  this is  like  starting a new project but  there is no any  file download.It was just link redirecting from : http://sourceforge.net/projects/apwlibrary/
 to 
http://coderesearchlabs.com/androidpdfwriter/

Comment: Why is it still accepted? Is it still valid? We have 2013 now! ;)

Comment: Library still valid as of today.

Comment: I agree with APW Library, a truly Android PDF Lib, But the problem is it is in a very early version, i am still writing routines to suit my needs according to the following sources :
[Adobe PSD Format](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/technology/pdfs/PDF_Day_A_Look_Inside.pdf)
, [GNU PDF](http://www.gnupdf.org/Category:PDF), [Adobe Supplement ISO 32000](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/adobe_supplement_iso32000_1.pdf), and a whole lot of other resources found at google.

Answer (score 6):

This might help you

http://androiddeveloperspot.blogspot.com/2013/05/android-pdf-reader-open-source-code.html

[PDF Library to rendering the PDF files in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096228/pdf-library-to-rendering-the-pdf-files-in-android)

<strike>You can also try pdfbox</strike>

http://pdfbox.apache.org/

You can chk this post

http://markmail.org/message/b2xjozidt32rhuyq#query:pdfbox%20android+page:1+mid:ipq7pviignd4cpja+state:results

Comment: PDFBOx is not gonna work with Android.

Comment: Though I have not tested,but these `StackOverflow` answers state that due to `AWT`, `pdfbox` can't be used on `Android`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696157/pdfbox-for-processing-pdf-in-android

Comment: There's now a PDFBox port for Android: https://github.com/Birdbrain2/PdfBox-Android

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [**MuPDF**](http://mupdf.com/).

MuPDF uses a very small footprint and has nearly-complete support for all features of PDF-1.7. It is the base for the quite popular (Windows) SumatraPDF viewer, but it has been ported to Android and iOS too.

Then also have a [look at all the questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mupdf) that have been asked on this website concerning MuPDF.

Comment: take note that is not free for commercial apps

Comment: @BudaFlorin: maybe you look up the fine differences between "free as in beer" and "free as in liberty" for once? Also the fine differences between "commercial" applications and "proprietary" applications or software? A software can well be commercial (see RedHat) without being closed source or proprietary, and a "free" (as in beer) one can  still be closed source (see many shareware programms, or many Android apps).

Comment: @BudaFlorin: If your comment did read *'Take note that MuPDF is not free for closed source apps'* it would be more appropriate and exact...

Comment: :) Yes, you're right :)  is not free for commercial apps which are't open source

Comment: @BudaFlorin: it's also not free (gratis) for non-commercial apps which aren't open source.

Answer (score 1):

IText seems to work fine.

To fix the affineTransform compilation issue you simply need to mark the "Micro PJAWT.jar" in iText for export in Eclipse so that your dependent project can use it for compilation purposes.

Comment: looks like it's very expensive

Comment: looks like it's MUCH expensive