# Open a pdf file inside a webview.

Tags: android, pdf

I have an app where I've button on a webpage that is rendered inside a webview.

Now on click of button , a pdf file gets downloaded , and the same would then need to be opened inside the same webview.

Answer (score 30):

attach a download listener to the web view and change the url as follows..

**"https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=https://www.example.com/xxxxxyyyyyxz.pdf"**

example

https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=https://www.adobe.com/support/products/enterprise/knowledgecenter/media/c4611_sample_explain.pdf

it's a link used to open pdf without downloading it...

I hope it solves your problem..

Comment: This is bad solution, because if google changes link, you will be forced to make application update. But after research, I guess this is the only one way :(

Comment: The URL no longer exists.

Comment: Please mark this as correct answer if solves your problem

Answer (score 10):

I've found that the [google viewer](http://docs.google.com/viewer) seems to work within the android browser for viewing online PDF files.  You could build a link to your pdf so that it is displayed in the viewer.  I've not tried doing that within a `WebView` though.

**UPDATE**

The link is dead, there is an explanation of how to get the functionality to still work at [this link](http://googlesystem.blogspot.co.uk/2015/02/google-docs-viewer-page-no-longer.html#gsc.tab=0).
In case *this* link also dies, here is the relevant section:

> While the page is no longer available as it redirects to Google Docs/Drive, you can still use the Google Docs Viewer. Paste this URL in a new tab:
>
> https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=
>
> and then paste the address of the document you want to view online. Here's an example:
>
> https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://research.google.com/archive/bigtable-osdi06.pdf

Comment: i tried using the google viewer with link something like below:-

Comment: the link is dead unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that the present android chrome based browser can support pdf. There are discussion about the same in android forums ( ex: [link1](http://androidcommunity.com/forums/f41/cant-view-download-pdf-from-browser-5829/) [link2](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Android%20Market/thread?tid=7e2236b3b9edbcad&hl=en))

Your best bet to show pdf is to have adobe pdf reader for android installed.(or concisely put, not possible in web view)

Comment: thanks.so are you saying that the only possible solution is to open the pdf url contents , save the file on sdcard/phone memory as a .pdf file and then open inside a separate activity?

Comment: Yes. Of course you can decorate the activity window to look like a web view, but at least according to me, its an unnecessary hack.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any browser other than Chrome supports rendering PDFs without a plugin or third party tool. It's probably easier to let the user use his own app to open PDFs.

I used the IText PDF library mentioned in this thread 
[Android : Is there any free PDF library for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530780/android-is-there-any-free-pdf-library-for-android) for a sample project. You could try getting using this API to get the PDF page as an image. I am not familiar with every aspect of Itext so it might have better way to do this.