# Open links in webview android html

Tags: android, html, pdf, webview, hyperlink

I am developing a webbased app for android, winpho and ios. One of the sections has a link to download a pdf.

In winpho and ios, keep pressing for a second open a menu to open, download or save document but in android, seems to do nothing. I can't open just pressing once the button or open in another window or nothing.

I don't know if I have to declare the button in other way in html or it just doesn't work in android.

Any idea about what is the problem? If you need my html code, just ask but it is just a normal link  with href=url.

I added the android part in which I open the webpage:

```
mywebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    if (savedInstanceState == null){
        mywebview.loadUrl(url);
}
```

The url is a normal webapage with a button on in. Clicking that button, the pdf is opened. In android chrome, it works.

Comment: Are you developing it with android sdk? If yes, plz paste the android code.

Comment: It is a browser dependant behavior. Otherwise look at this post, it can help you a bit to understand : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6816247/android-pdf-link-problem