# PDF Viewer support in mobile browser (iPhone & Android)

Tags: android, iphone, html, xhtml

Does `<object>` tag widely supported in mobile browser?! I'm trying to embed a PDF file but it seems that it is not supported.

I'm using the following html for viewing PDF

```
<object data="pdf/sample.pdf#view=Fit" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="400px"> 
    <p>It appears you don't have Adobe Reader or PDF support in this web browser. <a rel="external" href="pdf/sample.pdf">Click here to download the PDF</a></p>
</object>
```

and using the [PDFObject](http://pdfobject.com/) but both of them are not working in mobile browsers!

Comment: "mobile browsers" is **too** generic. which one are u targeting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If embedding isn't important to you you could just link to the PDF on a seperate page.

Safari (and UIWebViews) supports the rendering of PDFs, im not a 100% sure about Android but I suspect its a similar story.

[image: PDF in safari]

Comment: Android does NOT support this

Answer (score 8):

No browsers can support native rendering of PDF files without a plugin (except Google Chrome as claimed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4947993/184184)).

But you can use Google Docs Viewer to display PDF files inside a webpage like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6040247/184184).

Answer (score 4):

Load your url inside iframe using google docs

```
<iframe id="pdfviewer" src="http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=YOUR_URL_HERE&amp;embedded=true" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
```

Comment: If you are in Europe, you do not want to do that (GDPR+Schrems II)