# How to open local PDF file in WebView in Android?

Tags: android, pdf, webview

I want to open local (SD card) PDF file in a WebView.

I already tried this:

```
webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/test.pdf");

final Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);

webview.loadUrl(uri.toString());
```

But it's still not opening it, so let me know how I can open a PDF in WebView?

Comment: Try this webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://myurl.com/demo.pdf");

Answer (score 30):

I know, this question is old.

But I really like the approach of Xamarin to make use of the pdf.js from Mozilla. It works on older Android versions, you don't need a special PDF Viewer app for this and you can easily display a PDF *inside* of your apps views hierarchy.

Git for this:
https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/

Additional default options (like standard zoom):
https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Viewer-options

Just add the pdfjs files to your Assets directory:

[image]

And call it the following way:

```
// Assuming you got your pdf file:
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/test.pdf");

webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=" + file.getAbsolutePath() + "#zoom=page-width");
```

Cool thing: If you want to reduce the amount of functionalities / controls. Go to the Assets/pdfjs/web/viewer.html file and mark certain controls as hidden.
With

```
style="display: none;"
```

E.g. If you don't like the right toolbar:

```
<div id="toolbarViewerRight" style="display: none;">...</div>
```

**Update**

> 'URL scheme "file" is not supported'

Might occur for newer versions of pdfjs. With version `1.8.188` this error does not appear.

Comment: Awesome answer :)

Comment: Can pdf inside Android Project assets folder be opnened?

Comment: @CGR You will need a file‘s reference, which also needs to be available for the script, so maybe you need to copy the file locally from the assets folder first: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38504987

Comment: Lepidopteron thanks a lot, it worked great. I have pdf in assets, I copied it in private folder inside my app and opened it from there - no problems, no permissions mess. Used latest pdfjs 1.8.188

Comment: @BorisGafurov Glad it helped you! :-)

Comment: @Pihu Yes, it will

Comment: But i am unable to run this on Nougat Devices

Comment: Yeah, it runs finally now.. But it is very slow.

Comment: pdf.js zip file is around 40MB....I have to increase my app size by this much amout?

Comment: @pallavbohara the apk zips the files once again, so it will not increase the apk size of 40MB, but rather a smaller value. I did not validate the impact on the apk's size, tho.

Comment: @NiyasNazar it should, so far I did not stumble over an API, which did not work anymore. If you do, please do edit my answer and add your observations made.

Comment: @Lepidopteron How would you make it work that way, while on the internet you can find so many threads about pdf.js not supporting the `file:///` fetching? Exact err message is 'URL scheme "file" is not supported' and you can find lots of threads about it. How does this work for you?

Comment: @RadekKłos this approach renders the PDF with the framework - this requires some work if you‘d like to implement it yourself. Whilst the „file:///„ approach would make use of the system rendering.

Comment: @RadekKłos I was wondering the same and so I tried an older version of pdfjs, 1.8.188 version, mentioned in a comment above. And it worked. Instead it doesn't work with the latest version 2.1.266. So the URL scheme "file" not supported is a recent change.

Comment: @Lepidopteron - I'm hoping you or someone is still keeping an eye on this. I'm still having issues getting this to work in a native Android app. Using 1.8.188 version. Initially I was getting issues about SystemJS not being defined, however I npm install systemjs to the pdfjs package in my Android project. However now I'm getitng a different error:

Failed to load file:///android_asset/pdfjs/web/app.js: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, https.", source: file:///android_asset/pdfjs/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js (4)

Comment: Ah now this issue is back to the unsupported file protocol scheme regarding trying to access the l10n.js stuff for localisation. Did anyone exclude this somehow?

Answer (score 5):

As @Sameer replied in your comment above, the only solution to view PDF in webview is through Google Docs' online viewer which will render and send back a readable version to your app.

Previously discussed here

- [Open PDF in a WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434487/open-pdf-in-a-webview)
- [Open a pdf file inside a webview.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947591/open-a-pdf-file-inside-a-webview)

Comment: @androidsanta nop, it was to be loaded from web.

Comment: This work only with a remote PDF. If you want to open a local file like @girishce26, you have to use the CSmith's solution or this external plugin  https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview

Answer (score 3):

After going through several posts I came across [this](http://qr.ae/TU1tO4) simple answer on Quora which pretty much do the work. Following are steps:-

Add this dependency in your gradle file:

```
compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.0.3'
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
 <com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
    android:id="@+id/pdfView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     />
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package pdfviewer.pdfviewer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.listener.OnLoadCompleteListener;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.listener.OnPageChangeListener;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.scroll.DefaultScrollHandle;
import com.shockwave.pdfium.PdfDocument;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnPageChangeListener,OnLoadCompleteListener{
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    public static final String SAMPLE_FILE = "sample_pdf.pdf";
    PDFView pdfView;
    Integer pageNumber = 0;
    String pdfFileName;

    @Override    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        pdfView= (PDFView)findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
        displayFromAsset(SAMPLE_FILE);
    }

    private void displayFromAsset(String assetFileName) {
        pdfFileName = assetFileName;

        pdfView.fromAsset(SAMPLE_FILE)
                .defaultPage(pageNumber)
                .enableSwipe(true)

                .swipeHorizontal(false)
                .onPageChange(this)
                .enableAnnotationRendering(true)
                .onLoad(this)
                .scrollHandle(new DefaultScrollHandle(this))
                .load();
    }


    @Override    public void onPageChanged(int page, int pageCount) {
        pageNumber = page;
        setTitle(String.format("%s %s / %s", pdfFileName, page + 1, pageCount));
    }


    @Override    public void loadComplete(int nbPages) {
        PdfDocument.Meta meta = pdfView.getDocumentMeta();
        printBookmarksTree(pdfView.getTableOfContents(), "-");

    }

    public void printBookmarksTree(List<PdfDocument.Bookmark> tree, String sep) {
        for (PdfDocument.Bookmark b : tree) {

            Log.e(TAG, String.format("%s %s, p %d", sep, b.getTitle(), b.getPageIdx()));

            if (b.hasChildren()) {
                printBookmarksTree(b.getChildren(), sep + "-");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

You have to make sure that your asset folder contains sample_pdf.pdf (Library also support opening pdf from Uri and SDCard)

[image]

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot.  Using an Intent, you can open the PDF in an external viewer application like Acrobat Reader:

```
try
{
 Intent intentUrl = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 intentUrl.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
 intentUrl.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
 mActivity.startActivity(intentUrl);
}
catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
{
 Toast.makeText(mActivity, "No PDF Viewer Installed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From android **OS 5.0(lollipop) on-wards** you can use **`PdfRenderer instead of webview/library.`** You can use this class to show pdf's within the app.

If you want to support OS lower than that you can use a library/other approach mentioned in other answer as there is no native support.

Read more about it from the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer), you can also refer this [example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-PdfRendererBasic)

Answer (score 1):

**WebView** don't provide direct functionality to **open PDF** from **local** storage. You can open pdf in external **PDFViewer applications**.

Wait it will take user to **different application**.

Now without using any **extra library** to open a **PDF** we can use **PdfRenderer** class to render a PDF.

**PdfRenderer** can render pdf on **bitmap**.
Bitmap can be drawn to **Image View** to show the **PDF** in your application.

```
// create a new renderer
 PdfRenderer renderer = new PdfRenderer(getSeekableFileDescriptor());

 // let us just render all pages
 final int pageCount = renderer.getPageCount();
 for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) {
     Page page = renderer.openPage(i);

     // say we render for showing on the screen
     page.render(mBitmap, null, null, Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);

     // do stuff with the bitmap

     // close the page
     page.close();
 }

 // close the renderer
 renderer.close();
```

Read more about it from the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. Also, the same link already exists in a better-expanded answer. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33395794)

Comment: @Adinia, I will edit the answer with proper explanation.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the SkewPdfView library for loading pdf from remote or local urls.

First of all, Add following in your root build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

and add the `SkewPdfView` Library as:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.naya-aastra:SkewPdfView:1.1'
}
```

Now Include SkewPdfView in your layout:

```
<com.nayaastra.skewpdfview.SkewPdfView
    android:id="@+id/skewPdfView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Save all the local files in assets folder and then use SkewPdfView as follows.
Load a PDF file programmatically as:

```
SkewPdfView skewPdfView;
skewPdfView = findViewById(R.id.skewPdfView);
String pdfLink = "LINK TO ASSET FILE";
skewPdfView.loadPdf(pdfLink);
```

P.S.  link of SkewPdfView library

[SkewPdfView Github Page](https://github.com/naya-aastra/SkewPdfView)

Answer (score -1):

WebView can easily be used for displaying PDF file from a web url but if you have local PDF file, then it becomes a pain.

In my case i first stored a reference of my local file:-

```
File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null),"your_pdf_file.pdf");
```

Then i obtained file path URI of my local PDF file using FileProvider and started an intent for opening it using existing applications that can open PDF documents:-

```
try{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(FileProvider.getUriForFile(BaseActivity.this,BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID +".provider",file), "application/pdf");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    Toast.makeText(BaseActivity.this,"No Application Available to View PDF",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Also to use FileProvider API, you need to declare it in manifest as:-

```
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
```

And declare file_paths.xml under XML resource folder as:-

```
<paths>
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Answer (score -2):

WebView can not open a .pdf file. The most popular solution (google docs' url + your url in WebView) just shows you converted by google docs pictures. 
However there is still no simple way to open .pdf from url.

Comment: It's not a valid solution any more! Don't use it.