# Pdf file is not viewing in android app

Tags: pdf, android

Anyone can help in this code, the pdf file is not loading in app and just showing blank white screen, Logcat showing FileNotFoundExeeption: /storage/sdcard/raw/ourpdf.pdf.

i am trying to make an app that will show information while i click buttons and every button will be active for specific pdf file reading.  Any specific help please.

Thanks for help

part1

```
package com.code.androidpdf;
```

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
//Globals:
private WebView wv;
private int ViewSize = 0;

//OnCreate Method:
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //Settings
    PDFImage.sShowImages = true; // show images
    PDFPaint.s_doAntiAlias = true; // make text smooth
    HardReference.sKeepCaches = true; // save images in cache

    //Setup above
    wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);//show zoom buttons
    wv.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);//allow zoom
    //get the width of the webview
    wv.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout()
        {
            ViewSize = wv.getWidth();
            wv.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        }
    });

    pdfLoadImages();//load images
```

}

```
private void pdfLoadImages() {
    try
    {
        // run async
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>()
                {
                    // create and show a progress dialog
                    ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Opening...");

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
                    {
                        //after async close progress dialog
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            // select a document and get bytes
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/randompdf.pdf");
                            RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
                            FileChannel channel = raf.getChannel();
                            net.sf.andpdf.nio.ByteBuffer bb = null ;
                            raf.close();
                            // create a pdf doc
                            PDFFile pdf = new PDFFile(bb);
                            //Get the first page from the pdf doc
                            PDFPage PDFpage = pdf.getPage(1, true);
                            //create a scaling value according to the WebView Width
                            final float scale = ViewSize / PDFpage.getWidth() * 0.95f;
                            //convert the page into a bitmap with a scaling value
                            Bitmap page = PDFpage.getImage((int)(PDFpage.getWidth() * scale), (int)(PDFpage.getHeight() * scale), null, true, true);
                            //save the bitmap to a byte array
                            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            page.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                            stream.close();
                            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
                            //convert the byte array to a base64 string
                            String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
                            //create the html + add the first image to the html
                            String html = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body bgcolor=\"#7f7f7f\"><img src=\"data:image/png;base64,"+base64+"\" hspace=10 vspace=10><br>";
                            //loop through the rest of the pages and repeat the above
                            for(int i = 2; i <= pdf.getNumPages(); i++)
                            {
                                PDFpage = pdf.getPage(i, true);
                                page = PDFpage.getImage((int)(PDFpage.getWidth() * scale), (int)(PDFpage.getHeight() * scale), null, true, true);
                                stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                page.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                                stream.close();
                                byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
                                base64 = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
                                html += "<img src=\"data:image/png;base64,"+base64+"\" hspace=10 vspace=10><br>";
                            }
                            html += "</body></html>";
                            //load the html in the webview
                            wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, "text/html","UTF-8", "");
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Log.d("CounterA", e.toString());
                    }
                        return null;
                    }
                }.execute();
                System.gc();// run GC
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.d("error", e.toString());
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Where is the PDF file stored?

Comment: the PDF file saved in raw folder

Comment: the pdf file saved in res> raw folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is (sadly) not possible to view a PDF that is stored locally in your devices. Android L has introduced the feature. So, to display a PDF , you have two options:

1. See this answer for using webview
   [How to open local pdf file in webview in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613505/how-to-open-local-pdf-file-in-webview-in-android) (note that this requires an internet connection)
2. Use a third party pdf Viewer.

You can also send an intent for other apps to handle your pdf.

Comment: i am using  https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library this, but not working, can you give me any easier way, thanks

Comment: ask another question for that, i will answer.Accept this answer

Comment: Can u give me ways or tips how can i easily load pdf files by clicking buttons, i am a junior app developer, will be very thankful to you for your suggesion

Comment: That is exactly what my answer is about

Answer (score 0):

You can get an InputStream for the file using

```
getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.ourpdf)
```

Docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResource(int)

Comment: can you give me easier way to view pdf , will be very thankful

Comment: there is a github project based on MuPDF. by a user called joniks. see that. It is the easiest to use that comes to my mind