# Load a file from Asset using Xamarin android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, assets

I want to load a file from the Asset, I found the solution but with Java. How can I convert following Java code  to c#.

```
public String loadKMLFromAsset() {

    String kmlData = null;
    try {

        InputStream is = getAssets().open("yourKMLFile");

        int size = is.available();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

        is.read(buffer);

        is.close();

        kmlData = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return kmlData;

}
```

Comment: I'd suggest you to accept @mmushtaq since it's correct.

Answer (score 11):

Use [AssetManager](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_6_-_using_android_assets/)

```
// Read the contents of our asset
string content;
AssetManager assets = this.Assets;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader (assets.Open ("read_asset.txt")))
{
    content = sr.ReadToEnd ();
}
```

Comment: I see this is pulled directly from the Xamarin documentation: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_6_-_using_android_assets/#Reading_Assets

Would there be any issue with reducing this code to directly use the Assets property of the activity?

Comment: What import or using statement do I need to make this work? For me Visual Studio doesn't recognize AssetManager

Comment: This seems to assume you are inheriting from `Activity`. How do we access AssetManager if inheriting from `Instrumentation`?

Comment: That was pulled straight from the documentation ands does not help much.  The question is what are the supporting references, because without them that code fails.

Answer (score 0):

Use BinaryReader instead of streamReader, if u are working with files such as db, kml, shapefiles,, video formats, etc. StreamReader reads only strings or just plain text, so when reading binary file some of the content may be skipped, since streamreader doesnt read byte by byte

Answer (score -1):

This code writes the asset file to a file in your mobile file system:

```
 if (!System.IO.File.Exists("yourKMLFile_mobile"))
        {

                var s = Resources.OpenRawResource(Resource.Raw.yourKMLFile);

                FileStream writeStream = new FileStream("yourKMLFile_mobile", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
                ReadWriteStream(s, writeStream);
            }
```

Comment: I think you're confusing the question since your answer is fine, if he wanted to read a raw file not an asset file. Please check the other answer.