# Open local pdf file on webview

Tags: android, pdf-viewer

How can I open a pdf file from my android device(from download folder) on a webview? I tried to open pdf on webview but it supports only web url.Is it possible to open local pdf file on webview. I tried barteksc library, but it is a very large file. Any solutions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613505/how-to-open-local-pdf-file-in-webview-in-android

Comment: barteksc's library is indeed a large library because it contains native libraries for all CPU architectures. Use ABI splits to generate separate APK for different CPU architecture so that the app size will be reduced.

Comment: webview is not designed to open PDF files, it can only show HTML pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you use the **native feature `PdfRenderer` instead of `webview`.**
From android **OS 5.0(lollipop)** on-wards you can use this class to show pdf's within the app. If you want to support OS lower than that you can use a library as there is no native support

Read more about the class from the docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer), you can  also refer this [example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-PdfRendererBasic) provided by google

Comment: you are welcome @ShantoGeorge , let me know how it works out

Comment: awesome happy coding