# Where is the flutter asset bundle located?

Tags: android, flutter

The [docs](https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#introduction) say

> During a build, Flutter places assets into a special archive called the asset bundle, which apps can read from at runtime.

If I want to refer to the assets folder in places like webviews, I can't do that since I don't know the path of the asset folder on device.

I tried the `file:///android_assets` url but that doesn't work.

Specifically, I am looking to get [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43087397/7061265) working.

Comment: https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/

Comment: Try This [Link](https://flutter-io-deploy-one.firebaseapp.com/assets-and-images/)

Comment: @pskink
I want the path of the assets, so that I can use it outside of the context of flutter.

The above links, are literally linked in my question.

All flutter gives is an interface to read the file, but doesn't tell me its canonical path on the OS.

Comment: what do you want to achieve actually?

Comment: I want to be able to access the flutter assets from 1.) native code 2.) webviews.

Right now, doing that requires me to copy the contents to  to like a cache directory, and then I can use that file. But as you can imagine, this gets really inefficient with large files.

Comment: so i gave you a link in my first comment... did you try it?

Comment: I went there earlier (a couple of times), but somehow missed the "Sharing assets with the underlying platform" part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the flutter assets from native code.

See [Sharing assets with the underlying platform](https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#sharing-assets-with-the-underlying-platform).

Related github [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11892).