# Open local file in pdf.js android webview ("file" is not supported error)

Tags: android, webview, pdf.js

I'm trying to follow the answer stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43087397/9459815). Based on the comments, loading a local file using pdf.js in android webview should work but I am getting the below error:

```
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(18556)] "Fetch API cannot load file:///android_asset/www/pdfjs/web/tracemonkey.pdf. URL scheme "file" is not supported.", source: file:///android_asset/www/pdfjs/build/pdf.js (18556)
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(13127)] "Uncaught (in promise) DataCloneError: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Worker': TypeError: Failed to fetch could not be cloned.", source: file:///android_asset/www/pdfjs/build/pdf.js (13127)
    [INFO:CONSOLE(985)] "Uncaught (in promise) Error: An error occurred while loading the PDF.", source: file:///android_asset/www/pdfjs/web/viewer.js (985)
```

Here is my code:

```
class PDFViewerLocalActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.pdfviewer_layout)

        val webView = findViewById(R.id.pdfViewer) as WebView
        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webView.settings.allowFileAccessFromFileURLs = true
        webView.settings.allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true
        webView.settings.builtInZoomControls = true
        webView.webChromeClient = WebChromeClient()

        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=tracemonkey.pdf")

    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this was a dumb question. I already put the following permissions in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

But forgot that for API 23 and above you have to request permission at run time. So, just added the code to request permissions and it worked.

```
@TargetApi(23)
fun askPermissions() {
    val permissions = arrayOf("android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE")
    val requestCode = 200
    requestPermissions(permissions, requestCode)
}
```