# How to view downloaded PDF inside android app?

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, pdf.js

I am trying to view some pdf documents within my android app, which have been downloaded to the storage. I liked the idea of using Mozilla pdfjs library and so far I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613505/how-to-open-local-pdf-file-in-webview-in-android?answertab=active#tab-top) but no success.

```
webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
webView.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
webView.settings.useWideViewPort = true
webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
webView.settings.allowFileAccessFromFileURLs = true
webView.settings.allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true
webView.settings.mixedContentMode = WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW
webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
    override fun onReceivedSslError(
        view: WebView?,
        handler: SslErrorHandler?,
        error: SslError?
    ) {
        handler?.proceed()
    }
}
webView.setWebChromeClient(object : WebChromeClient() {

    override fun onProgressChanged(view: WebView?, newProgress: Int) {
        super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress)
        if (newProgress == 100) {
            showToast("Progress complete")
        }
    }
})
webView.setWebChromeClient(object : WebChromeClient() {
    override fun onProgressChanged(view: WebView?, newProgress: Int) {
        super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress)
        if (newProgress == 100) {
            showToast("Progress complete")
        }
    }
})
val url = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/CallE/TrainingPdf.pdf")
println(url)
val newUrl = "file:///android_asset/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=" + url
webView.loadUrl(newUrl)
```

[image]

Comment: don't forget to ask for permissions to access the storage. Because you have repeated the setWebChromeClient method?

Comment: I have already added these permission in the manifest file

READ_PHONE_STATE    
WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: for API> = 23 it should be requested at runtime https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting