# android pdf from http stream

Tags: android, pdf, stream

Is is possible to open PDF from a stream (https:\serever\res\pedstream) in android web view or even in the pdf viewer installed in android device?

My point is event if the PDF viewer is not installed in the device we should be able to open it in webview component. And to view the PDF without downloading the file locally.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open a pdf file inside a webview.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947591/open-a-pdf-file-inside-a-webview)