# how to view the pdf file in my emulator

Tags: android, pdf

I have download pdf files in my sdcard but when i click them to open in my emulator it gives a toast

"Cannot open file" please help me to read the pdf file ....
Please tell me what is wrong in this code.....

```
File file=new File("/sdcard/Android.Essentials.pdf");
 if (file.exists())
 {
Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
try {

  startActivity(intent);
   finish();
}
catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
Toast.makeText(PdffileActivity.this,
"No Application Available to View PDF",
 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```

Comment: Why you are calling startActivity(intent); two times .one before try block and one inside try block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To launch an Intent on a PDF file, the mobile device should have installed a program that can read PDF documents.

If you do not want the user to have a PDF reader's installed, you must modify your application to be able to read PDF documents.

On this post talk about PDF libraries for Android: [Android : Is there any free PDF library for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530780/android-is-there-any-free-pdf-library-for-android)

Comment: :i also added the lib named folder containing all iText jar files parallel to the src folder .. still i am not able to read ....

Comment: @AmitParjapati To use the iText library you should not open the PDF document with a startIntent. Need to open following the iText library documentation.

Answer (score 3):

You **need to install** any PDF Reader App in your emulator.

Your intent is looking for any installed PDF reader and in your emulator may be there is no PDF reader installed.

Just install [this](http://andpdf.sourceforge.net/) app in your emulator

Comment: if he had no pdf reader app installed it would have given him ActivityNotFoundException exception

Comment: @Mihir Sir why my application not reading the pdf file in emulator. In webview it is viewing easily

Comment: one link i have already given in the ans. You can also try with http://code.google.com/p/vudroid/downloads/detail?name=vudroid-1.4.apk

Comment: sir from your previous link i cannot find the package installer in my eclipse.. http://andpdf.sourceforge.net/

Comment: you need to install apk in emulator. just google it you will find the solution.

Comment: This app is buggy. Sometimes only some PDF commands are executed. Got different result on opening the same PDF twice!

Answer (score 2):

**Just download apk from this link to view Pdf files on emulator.**

[PdfViewerApk for Emulator](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5VU1Fv1J5NzX2htbkFjVTMwU2c)

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for. Quick and easy! Thanks!

Comment: Just tried that, today. It told me "Sorry, the PDF is corrupt" on a known good PDF.