# PDF Library to rendering the PDF files in Android

Tags: java, android, pdf, epub

I need a PDF library For Android that can read the PDF Files and access to edit and change their contents. Some of Library I have already used :

1. iText Pdf Library(http://itextpdf.com/)
2. PdfViewer

But there is problem in Library first one is useful if having only text in pdf. It will not take the images and second changes the pdf to images so that cannot editable.

Comment: Try MuPDF http://www.mupdf.com/ Checkout http://mupdf.blogspot.sg/

Comment: what are the other libraries available for rendering pdf files in ANdroid

Comment: You can also try [PlugPDF SDK for Android](http://componentwanted.com/plugpdf-sdk-ios-and-android-unlimited/)

Answer (score 17):

PDF read/writing is a **big** problem for Android. A quick search on Stackoverflow will reveal **many** developers looking for solutions. So far, the most popular solution is to use a webview and [use the google docs engine to render the PDF](http://www.mupdf.com/)

There are also :

- [MuPDF](http://www.mupdf.com/)
- [Android PDF Viewer Library](https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library)

Comment: The link to google docs actually goes to MuPDF.

Comment: can anyone tell me how to use PDF Viewer Library to get pinch zoom facility.currently zoom facility is there,but we need to click button.

Comment: @asliyanage Ask the new question on Stack Overflow please

Comment: @steipete does it support vectors drawings in pdf ? If someone wants infinite zoom for instance

Comment: I have used MuPDF, but am unable to render large pdf files ... 1.5Mb and above. except it is working smooth