# Is it possible to view pdf files within an app in android?

Tags: android, pdf

I'm working on an app that will need to open a pdf inside the app itself. Is this even an option or does the user have to view the pdf in a different app altogether?

Comment: Worked on an android app and had to do in app pdf open with native code (C++), so it can be done but if you want to have less hassles and it is not really a problem. Let the intent decide the appropriate pdf reader to open it.

Comment: I had a feeling that would be the answer... apparently it can be done with a webview but the pdf needs to be viewed offline.

Comment: But does the webview provide ease of usage when compared to a dedicated reader which I feel is a NO.

Comment: I agree. A dedicated reader would be more reliable and faster. I was hoping i could just open it inside my app. This is something I think the client was expecting so I'll need to explain this limitation to them.

Comment: Great but you can check out artifex mupdf out of curiosity.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096228/pdf-library-to-rendering-the-pdf-files-in-android

Comment: @Matt - I wish I could just use google dogs in the webview like that link suggests. However it has to be available offline.

Answer (score 0):

This is open source for open pdf file in app, maybe you can try it
[android-pdfviewer](https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview)