# How can i parse PDF file in android?

Tags: java, android, pdf, pdf-generation

I am developing android application. This application allows the user to highlight words in PDF file. Then these words must be extracted, so how can I parse the PDF file to get extracted words from the file without any library? Can any one help me?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please edit your question to include your attempts and any code that you have used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to code it yourself if you don't want to use a libary. There isn't any build-in classes in Android SDK for PDF manipulation.

However you have to use a Libary and have a look at this question:

[PDF Library to rendering the PDF files in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096228/pdf-library-to-rendering-the-pdf-files-in-android)

Comment: Thank you for your replay,
If I want to write code by my self , can i read the PDFfile like other text file? an how can i get the background color of the text?

Comment: You can't do that because you have to use the SDK from Adobe and that is managed code.  so it would be very difficult.  Why don't you want to use a library?

Answer (score 0):

You can parse PDF easily on android easily using the iText library as like I've done it on my project by parsing a pdf file from assets and displaying it in the android listview.

iTextG Link: https://developers.itextpdf.com/itextg-android

```
assetManager = getAssets();

try{
    InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("sample.pdf");
    String parsedText = "";
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputStream);
    int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        parsedText = parsedText + PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, i + 1).trim() + "\n";

    String[] data = parsedText.split("\n");

    for(String d : data){
        patients.add(d);
    }

    reader.close();

}catch (FileNotFoundException e){
    Toast.makeText(this, "File Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}catch (IOException e){
    Toast.makeText(this, "IO Error reading input stream", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Code-only answers are discouraged, as they provide no insight into how the problem was solved. Please update your solution with an explanation of how your code solves the OP's problem :)