# Can I use the iText library in my Android project?

Tags: android, pdf, itext

I need convert image to PDF document, I have 15 SDK (If I had 19 SDK I use PdfDocument). I find good library for my task, it's iText. I add its lib to my project:

```
compile 'com.itextpdf:itext-pdfa:5.5.8'
```

But then I find some information about license and now I can't understand if I can use this library in my project or not? And if not please tell me what the free library to convert PDF.

Comment: For Android, you need iTextG, which is the Android port of iText. Your Android project may not work with regular iText. You need to add iTextG manually. Sorry, it's not yet on Maven or any of the other popular Java distribution systems. We're looking into that.

Comment: Also your question is not a technical question but a question about licensing. That is not a valid topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is latest version of itext that is not AGPL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321207/what-is-latest-version-of-itext-that-is-not-agpl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> iText is licensed as AGPL software.
>
> AGPL is a free / open source software license.
>
> This doesn't mean the software is gratis!
>
> Buying a license is mandatory as soon as you develop commercial activities distributing the iText software inside your product or deploying it on a network without disclosing the source code of your own applications under the AGPL license. These activities include:
>
> offering paid services to customers as an ASP
> serving PDFs on the fly in the cloud or in a web application
> shipping iText with a closed source product

If you are using for learning, you can use it, no problem. But, you can not use this library without its license if you have commercial plans for your app.

Look at [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096228/pdf-library-to-rendering-the-pdf-files-in-android).

Comment: This means that I can not use the library in a product that will play for example on the play market?

Comment: Yes, you can't. If you're going to release an app, consider paying the license or looking for another solution.

Comment: thanks, do you happen to know a good free library for converting images to pdf?

Comment: thanks, but i think example for this topik use `iText`

Comment: That's not correct, you can still use iText for a commercial project without buying a commercial license IF you release your own project also with an AGPL (or compatible) license. For a lot of people, making their software open source defeats the purpose of having commercial software, but this is a bad assumption. iText itself is the example that software can be commercial and open source at the same time.

Comment: My co-workers in the sales department may disagree with the above statement. *g*