# library pdfview in android project

Tags: android, pdfview

I'm using `pdfview` library in android .i have the problem in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24183472/how-to-open-pdf-in-android-using-pdfview). the accepted answer said that we should add [this folder](https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview/tree/master/android-pdfview/libs/armeabi-v7a) into  my project , but there is no description to do that .the question is : how can i add this folder as library ?

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096228/pdf-library-to-rendering-the-pdf-files-in-android

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the structure like [THIS](https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview/tree/master/android-pdfview)
You can see the libs directory with the others directories and files.

Right Click with mouse -> Create -> etc. And add the files.